# IServerXMLHTTPRequest2 equivalent to WebProxy::BypassProxyOnLocal from C#

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, http-proxy

I'm trying to port to Win32/C++ some C# code dealing with proxy settings for HTTP connection. I'm using [`IServerXMLHTTPRequest2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760236(v=vs.85)) interface, that closely resembles what C# is using.

But I can't seem to find the `BypassProxyOnLocal` property of the [WebProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webproxy?view=net-6.0) class in `IServerXMLHTTPRequest2`.

Any idea where is it?

Comment: You may need to check [WebProxy](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/webproxy.cs,184) source.

Comment: Why don't you use Wininet or WinHTTP. Especially WinHTTP which is update to latest web technologies (HTTP3, etc.). WinHTTP has a way to by pass proxy for local: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winhttp/ns-winhttp-winhttp_proxy_info

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT of nice, I didn't know that MSFT made such an easy reference to the .NET internals.